# Pass a string from the controller to a partial view as javascript function parameter

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a controller

```
public ActionResult controller(){
Viewclass view = new Viewclass();
... 
return PartialView("Tab", view);
}
```

In which the view class is something like, the string A and B is my compiled JSON string.

```
public class ViewClass
{public string A {get;set;}
public string B {get;set;}
}
```

In the Partial view, I want to do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
RunMap( @Model.A, @Model.B);
</script>
```

The problem is the " is parsed as &quot, like {&quotCity&quot:} into the function. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw` to treat the string as raw HTML (e.g MVC will not encode it)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   RunMap(@Html.Raw(Model.A), @Html.Raw(Model.B));
</script>
```

Of course, you need to make sure that the input (e.g the data) it handled carefully.

Answer (score 1):

This *should* work: `RunMap( "@Model.A", "@Model.B");`

If you want to pass them as JSON objects, then take out the quotes.

Comment: I got something like {&quot;Cities&quot;:[{&q....64635201372,&quot;Cities&quot;:0}}) in the result

Comment: How are you creating the JSON string? Maybe you can use `JsonValueProviderFactory` and declare your props as `Json`. Here's a related article: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx

Comment: I used a StringBuilder and create my own (since I need to add on some logics and please see my ViewClass). How can I correctly declare the return type to avoid this problem?